# Changing hostname reboot reverts back to original

Tags: linux, hostname

So, What I'm trying to do is simply change the hostname permanently. I can update the hostname but when a reboot is issued the original hostname is used!

I'm aware there is a file hostname located at: ***/etc/hostname***. I update this file and issue a reboot, however the hostname is back to the previous setting!

What I've tried:

1. Updating ***/etc/hosts*** file newhostname
2. Updating ***hosts*** file - 127.0.0.1 newhostname
3. reboot

I've also tried with sudo user and root!

Why is this happening?!

Thanks for any advice or suggestions, I feel like I've tried every other solution with no avail.

***EDIT:***

I've just updated the ***/etc/hostname*** file on a VM running debian 7 locally and it works as expected. Why doesn't this work when connected to a remote server with SSH?

Comment: Is the server using `dhcp`?

Comment: Not enough rep to add a comment. Have you tried hostname.sh?

Comment: Not using dhcp.

Comment: How are you checking what the hostname is? Are you just going off of what the prompt says? When you SSH into the server, do `echo $PS1`. I highly doubt someone has changed it, but you never know ....

Comment: I just issue 'hostname' after the reboot and it shows the old host name. It's a bit strange because it doesn't happen when I change the hostname on a VM.

Answer (score 9):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname servername.example.com
```

That's for RHEL 7 that is.

Comment: Same happened to my Debian setups. thx.

Answer (score 5):

Another reason why the host name gets reset could be the cloud-init package. This package is used to provision a host and can also be used to set the systems host name.

In the case of my Ubuntu system the `preserve_hostname` option was set to `false` in the file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`. Setting this option to `true`, will let a newly set host name survive a reboot.

Comment: I deployed a Debian image to OCI and was having this issue. This solutions was the fix to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/hosts` is meant as a first-step for DNS resolution. If you're trying to reach a host that's present there, it will use that record instead of querying DNS.

As you've discovered, `/etc/hostname` is one option for hostname changes in Debian.  In RHEL6, it's `/etc/sysconfig/network`, and in RHEL7 it's either the `hostnamectl` command or `/etc/hostname`.

Changing hostnames on Linux hosts can vary by distribution and release, so it's best to Google the procedure for your particular platform.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting runtime kernel parameter

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'kernel.hostname = YOUR_HOSTNAME' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
```

Apply your changes with

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Now simply, logout and log back in, your hostname should be the one you applied.